# Correct approach when multiple inheritance is needed (TypeScript)

Tags: oop, inheritance, typescript, multiple-inheritance

First of all [mixins](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2014/02/TypeScript-Mixins-Part-One/) are not the best solution, since my interfaces are large and I want to avoid writing empty implementations.

What I am looking for is which approach (technique) is the best for multiple inheritance. My problems is diamond inheritance (yes I read about diamond problem).

```
//                   -----------------------
//                   |         Edit        |
//                   -----------------------
//                  /                  \
//                 /                    \
//                /                      \
//    -----------------------         -----------------------
//    |     DataSetEdit     |         |        OEdit        |
//    -----------------------         -----------------------
//                    \                    /
//                     \                  /
//                      \                /
//                    -----------------------
//                    |     ODataSetEdit    |
//                    -----------------------
```

The logic is simple.

- Edit is basicaly some `<input type="textbox">` with some additional method for validation, masks, input checking ...
- OEdit extends edit with some additional methods for styling. Can get properties from server application (WebSocket), send events to server
- DataSetEdit adds methods and properties for handling edit properties (text, color, caption, placeholder ...) - automatically handle changes when current record has changed. (DataSet is class and its data is Object[].)
- ODataSetEdit extends OEdit functionality but need also DataSetEdit methods for handling changes on DataSet.

In one project I use DataSetEdit and in another I always use ODataSetEdit. So in project where ODataSetEdit is used, I only need to copy DataSetEdit functionality.

I do not want to duplicate code in DataSetEdit and ODataSetEdit.
I was thinking if I can solve this with:

- some static methods/properties approach
- decorators (maybe on constructor to extend class functionality)
- some static method on DataSetEdit which would be called from ODataSetEdit to extend OEdit functionality with DataSetEdit
- proxy methods and properties from ODataSetEdit to DataSetEdit
- some sort of [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) (how would design looks in this concrete example)

ODataSetEdit should extend OEdit but be able to use functionality added in DataSetEdit.

I think that the class structure is logic, how can I avoid need for multiple inheritance in my design? I am sure this is a common problem not related to TypeScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I avoid need for multiple inheritance in my design

Move the logic out of OEdit into functions / variables (feel free to use a namespace : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/namespaces.html to collect these into something meaningful) and then share them between OEdit and ODataSetEdit.

## More

Fundamentally you need to move the logic out into a place accessible by at least one direct child and the grand child. No two ways around it .

Comment: Also, several layers of inheritance is often a big design smell and a maintainance hazard, so moving to smaller abstractions (functions) is a big win.

Comment: Agree, also buy and read some books about that, but examples in books are to basic for me to transact it to my code.